# How much water can this hold

Tags: volume

I have a bin that has $24$x$24$ cm and is $34$ cm deep. How much water could it hold?
It's also in a cone-ish shape, the bottom part is $20$x$20$ cm. If possible answer considering the cone shape, if not then it's okay.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Try using mathjax to make your question more presentable.

Comment: Square tops and bottoms?

Comment: If you really have such a bin, you could just fill it with water, then empty the water into containers of known volume, and get the answer. So, I suspect you are lying about having such a bin.

Answer (score 2):

A "cone-ish" shape is a fustrum.

But this sounds like a truncated pyramid.  Either way the formula is about the same.

$\frac 13 (S^2 + Ss + s^2) h = \frac 13 (24^2 + 24\cdot 20  +20^2)34 = 16,501\ cm^3 = 16.5$ liters

Comment: @Catia - you can check this answer by filling your bin with water and finding out how much weight this added. Or use a measuring cup. It's a lot of water.

Comment: its made out of net, i cant fill it D: but thank you alot ^^

Comment: And, if the bases are circles, multiply by a factor of $\frac {\pi}{4} $.

Comment: If it is made out of net, then the container can't hold any water (which is what the question asks!)  However, if you want to test this "experimentally, but a large trash bag inside the container and fill that.